# How to set mean as base in regression model

Tags: r, regression, anova, categorical-data

```
Model  <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
Price  <- c(12,14,15,13,16,36,32,24,14,15,14,11,24,31)
region <- c("W","E","E","W","W","E","E","E","E","W","W","W","E","W")
dt <- data.frame(Model, Price, region)

fit <- lm(log(Price)~., data=dt)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = log(Price) ~ ., data = dt)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.53051 -0.18080 -0.01557  0.20122  0.59010 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.7980     0.2047  13.666 8.53e-08 ***
ModelB        0.3716     0.2409   1.542    0.154    
ModelC        0.3194     0.2409   1.326    0.214    
regionW      -0.2734     0.2146  -1.274    0.231    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Lets ignore the significant, I just make up some numbers. Right now, we set A as base, 0.37 means B has 37% higher price than A. But my question is can we set the mean of A:C as mean, the parameter show the difference to the mean of A,B,C?

Comment: Welcome to CV. I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you can *contrast* the average price of the combination of categories A, B and C? You can certainly do this but, if there are only 3 possible values -- A, B and C -- what is the contrast set against?

Comment: Actually I have six levels in my real data. I use contrasts = list(Region = "contr.sum"), but not sure if it is correct.

Comment: I don't know those commands but the idea behind contrasts is to balance a set of numbers such that, across the elements in the contrast, they sum up to zero. So, A, B and C could each be 1 or 0.33 and D, E and F could each be -1 or -0.33 -- if those are the comparisons you need to make. if there are elements you don't want included, set them to zero.

Comment: Although asked in the context of `R`, I think this is more of a conceptual / statistics understanding question than an R coding question. I think this should be considered on topic here.

Comment: Do you have the same number of observations in each level of the categorical variable?

Comment: I don't. I figured out use contrasts=list() only works for balanced dataset.